# How to Eliminate an Unseemly Seam in a Psvectorian bi-Colored Pspicture

Tags: xetex, color, pstricks, border, psvectorian

In the following code, I am trying to color the LHS of a `psipicture` blue and the RHS yellow; however, an "unseemly" seam appears down the middle of the picture.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}

\makeatletter
\def\psBoldVectorian{\@ifnextchar[\psBoldVectorian@i{\psBoldVectorian@i[]}}
\def\psBoldVectorian@i[#1]#2{%
  \rput(0,0){\psvectorian[#1]{#2}}%
  \rput(0.4pt,0.4pt){\psvectorian[#1]{#2}}%
  \rput(-0.4pt,-0.4pt){\psvectorian[#1]{#2}}%
}
\makeatother
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,8)%
\psframe[fillcolor=blue!35,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(0,8)
\psframe[fillcolor=yellow!75,fillstyle=solid](0,-5)(5,8)
\psframe[linecolor=white](-5,-5)(5,8)


% oiseaux
\rput[tr]{-30}(-1.3,5.15){\psvectorian[color=white,width=2.1cm]{57}}
\rput[tl]{30}(1.3,5.15){\psvectorian[color=white,width=2.1cm,mirror]{57}}
\rput[tr]{-30}(-1.3,5.15){\psvectorian[color=white,width=2.1cm]{57}}
\rput[tl]{30}(1.3,5.15){\psvectorian[color=white,width=2.1cm,mirror]{57}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

How may I eliminate the black seam so that the blue portion of the picture is contiguous with the yellow with no visible border? The code is compiled with `xelatex`. Thank you.

Comment: See the starred version of `\psframe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,8)
\psframe*[linecolor=blue!35](-5,-5)(0,8)
\psframe*[linecolor=yellow!75](0,-5)(5,8)

% oiseaux
\rput[tr]{-30}(-1.3,5.15){\psvectorian[color=white,width=2.1cm]{57}}
\rput[tl]{30}(1.3,5.15){\psvectorian[color=white,width=2.1cm,mirror]{57}}
\rput[tr]{-30}(-1.3,5.15){\psvectorian[color=white,width=2.1cm]{57}}
\rput[tl]{30}(1.3,5.15){\psvectorian[color=white,width=2.1cm,mirror]{57}}
\end{pspicture}%
```